# Compare functions

Tags: functions

How to prove f1 and f2 are equivalent?

In:

```
ReverseComposition[fs__] := Composition[Sequence @@ Reverse@{fs}]

partition[xs_] := Partition[xs, 10];
grid[xss_] := Grid[xss, Spacings -> {1, 1}];
f1 = ReverseComposition[Range, partition, grid]
f2 = RightComposition[Range, partition, grid]
f1 == f2
```

Out:
[image]

I think I should give one more example.

```
g1[x_] := If[Head[x] == Symbol, True, False]
g2[x_] := True
Through[(g1 == g2)[x]]
Through[(g1 == g2)[3]]
```

[image]

Comment: If only as `Through[(f1==f2)[x]]`, I guess. Nice question.

Comment: Evaluate something like `Simplify[f1[n] == f2[n]]` or `FindInstance[f1[n] != f2[n], n, Integers]`?

Comment: I guess that's what test case is for. In practical, many people do it like this and add more test cases when they find new corner cases/bugs. The four colour theorem was the first major theorem proved using a computer. Hopefully this isn't the case.

Comment: In general it is not possible to prove that two algorithms are the same. (This is a variation of so called [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)) But for some special cases one can prove equivalence. See [How do you check if two algorithms return the same result for any input?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2059). What kind of functions do you want to compare? Just left and right compositions or something more general?

Comment: @Shadowray, just left and right compositions.

Comment: I think you should define equivalent more precisely. If we add some up values to the test argument we could most probably create counter examples to all but trivial cases.

Comment: @Kuba For each element of the domain, two functions must yield the same result.

Comment: @UnchartedWorks and where is the domain specified?

Comment: @Kuba, your question is a hard one. The result of Through[(f1 == f2)[x]] is True, in this expression, x is a Symbol. Wolfram language is not a strong-type static language. I really don't know what the domain it is in this case. It should be natural numbers, however people can use anything as a input.

Comment: @Kuba and OP I think it stands to reason, that *generally* `Composition@@list == RightComposition@@(Reverse@list)`, however if evaluating members of `list` has side effects, MMA's evaluation sequence may lead to different results. In this case, even for comparing right/left compositions Shadowray is absolutely right that it's not possible to prove that two algorithms are the same.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I know, but the devil is in the details. That is a tricky question so it needs to be precisely stated.

Answer (score 6):

This is an obscure example, but it does show that functions with side-effects can render `Composition[h,g,f]` and `RightComposition[f,g,h]` non-equivalent.

Definitions:

```
f := (i++; # &)
g := (i *= 3; # &)
h := (i &)
```

Composition:

```
i = 2; Composition[h, g, f][x]
```

> ```
> 7
> ```

RightComposition:

```
i = 2; RightComposition[f, g, h][x]
```

> ```
> 9
> ```

Thus, for the most general case, Shadowray's comment

> In general it is not possible to prove that two algorithms are the same. (This is a variation of so called halting problem) But for some special cases one can prove equivalence. [...]

holds even for the special case of comparing `Composition` and `RightComposition`.

**Bonus edit:**

Here's how we can mitigate this:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Composition}, 
 SetAttributes[Composition, HoldAll];
 i = 2; Composition[h, g, f][x]
]
Internal`InheritedBlock[{RightComposition}, 
 SetAttributes[RightComposition, HoldAll];
 i = 2; RightComposition[f, g, h][x]
]
```

> ```
> 7
> 7
> ```

Comment: It's a good example. I just realised that f, g and h shouldn't have any side effects/states, otherwise they are not compositable.

Comment: +1 for the answer. its striking to see `Composition` and `RightComposition` yielding different results

Comment: @LLlAMnYP for clarification, does that mean with `RightComposition` somehow the first argument `f` gets evaluated whereas `f` in `Composition` is not evaluated beforehand. When I look at the Attributes for both `Composition` and `RightComposition` none have the attribute `HoldAll`?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I set the attribute of `RightComposition` to `HoldFirst` and it behaves just like `Composition`

Comment: @AliHashmi Both for `RightComposition` and `Composition` all three of `f,g,h` get evaluated *before* even constructing the expression `h[g[f[x]]]`. I designed `f,g,h` such that `f` and `g` have side effects such that their order of operation matters. When you give `RightComposition` `HoldFirst`, `f` is not evaluated before `g`, but only after when the expression transforms to `h[g[f[x]]]` (giving same result as `Composition` where `g` comes before `f`).

Comment: However, if they get a `HoldAll` attribute then in both cases *first* the expression `h[g[f[x]]]` is constructed and *then* `h,g,f` evaluate each in turn, executing their respective side-effects.

Comment: Since delayed own values with side effects can be something surprising for people coming from other languages, I think it should be stressed that it's evaluation of `f` and `g` symbols that have side effects here, and not functions that are results of this evaluation. Results of `comp = Composition[h, g, f]` and `rcomp = RightComposition[f, g, h]` evaluation are functions that are equivalent (up to "malicious" `UpValues` of arguments): `i = 2; comp[x] (* 2 *)`, `i = 2; rcomp[x]  (* 2 *)`.

Comment: If used functions, not symbols, have side effects: `f = (i++; #)&; g = (i *= 3; #)&; h = i&;`, then their compositions are still equivalent `i = 2; Composition[h, g, f][x] (* 9 *)`, `i = 2; RightComposition[f, g, h][x] (* 9 *)`.

Comment: @jku yes, this is subtly different, since Function Holds its arguments.